# Scan LAN ports for devices other than computers

Tags: port, local-area-network

I have a fingerprint device attached to a LAN and I want to figure out the port number used. I could not figure out from its settings and configuration, so I thought to do a port scan over the network. Are usual port scanners able to identify and communicate with such a device? I tried Advanced Port Scanner and Zenmap GUI and neither helped, Adv Port Scanner does not see the device and Zenmap identifies it as 'Host down'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/), which is a full-featured nmap GUI.
It has predefined scan types, including some to scan for remote OS based on certain signature/behavior found during the port scan.

EDIT: I see you already used zenmap without success. Be sure to enable "operating system detection" (see [here](https://nmap.org/zenmap/images/zenmap-multi-1220x700.png) for an image)

Answer (score 0):

If the device is on the LAN it will have an ip address, and you can use [NMAP](https://nmap.org) to scan for open ports on that address.